# How to verify XFF_IP is from a known Proxy or CDN while enforcing key in Google Cloud Armor Security Policy?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ip, rate-limiting

I'm currently working on a project where I want to apply rate limiting at the load balancer level to each user's IP address. The idea is to throttle any user that crosses a certain request limit in a given unit of time.

Note: I am using Google Cloud Armor.

The architecture involves a CDN in front of the load balancer. As I understand it, when using a CDN, the IP address that my load balancer sees for incoming requests is the CDN's IP, not the original client's IP.

I've already tried using XFF_IP for rate limiting and it seems to be working as expected. However, I'm not sure how to safeguard against potential spoofing of the XFF header. Any insights or recommendations would be appreciated.

I read Pulumi's documentation to gain understanding of the different keys I can enforce. XFF_IP is known to be faulty.

What measures can I take to prevent spoofing of the XFF header and ensure accurate rate limiting?